# Grafana generic oauth not working as expected

Tags: oauth, grafana

```
New to oAuth and Grafana
Grafana v9.0.0-pre
oAuth server - https://github.com/authlib/example-oauth2-server
```

Generic oauth config

```
[auth.generic_oauth]
name = OAuth
icon = signin
enabled = true
allow_sign_up = true
client_id = <>
client_secret = <>
scopes = profile
empty_scopes = false
email_attribute_name = 
email_attribute_path =
login_attribute_path =
name_attribute_path =
role_attribute_path =
role_attribute_strict = false
groups_attribute_path =
id_token_attribute_name =
team_ids_attribute_path =
auth_url = http://127.0.0.1:5000/oauth/authorize
token_url = http://127.0.0.1:5000/oauth/token
api_url = http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/me
teams_url =
allowed_domains =
team_ids =
allowed_organizations =
tls_skip_verify_insecure = true
tls_client_cert =
tls_client_key =
tls_client_ca =
use_pkce = false
```

oAuth Client Config

```
Client Info
  client_id: <>
  client_secret: <>
  client_id_issued_at: <>
  client_secret_expires_at: 0
Client Metadata
  client_name: grafana
  client_uri: http://localhost:3000/
  grant_types: ['authorization_code', 'password']
  redirect_uris: ['http://localhost:3000/login/generic_oauth']
  response_types: ['code']
  scope: profile
  token_endpoint_auth_method: client_secret_basic
```

I am able to see `Sign in with OAuth` button in the Grafana UI and signing in works as well. It redirects to the oAuth server to sign in there (if not already signed in) and then asks for consent and redirects back to Grafana and logs the user in.

Problems:

1. Signing out from oAuth server has no effect on Grafana, user is still logged in
2. Expiring the auth token, from both Grafana and oAuth has no effect on the logged in users, they continue to be logged in
3. Revoking token from oAuth server (updating the DB manually) has no effect on the logged in users, they continue to be logged in

Expectations:

1. Sign out of Grafana if token expires
2. Sign out of Grafana if token is revoked

Is the expectation correct here? An explanation on how generic oAuth should behave in Grafana would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect expectations.

1.) Access token is exchanged by Grafana for own session cookie, which may have different lifetime. Very likely your IDP server provides also refresh token, so Grafana can refresh access token, so user don't need to be signed out.

2.) That's possible, but backchannel logout must be implemented by used IDP and app (Grafana) = IDP broadcasts message "token is revoked" to the client (Grafana) and they will need to process that. Backchannel logout is not implemented in the Grafana.

Generally, access token should have short lifetime (e.g. 5 min) and token refresh should be in the place. If there is token revocation, then token refresh will faill and app should sign out a user. That is typical use case, when there is no support for backchannel logout.